# Reference request for characterisation of discrete valuations

Tags: reference-request, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

What I am asking for might be impossible, anyway let me try. Long time ago (between 2015 and 2019?) I remember reading a book, or maybe an article, related to $p$-adic numbers in which following proposition was given:

> Let $v$ be a valuation on field $K$. The following statements are equivalent:
>
> - $v$ is discrete, that is $v(K^\times) \cong \mathbb Z$,
> - ideal $\mathfrak m = (\pi)$ is principal
> - valuation ring $\mathcal O$ is a PID
> - valuation ring $\mathcal O$ is noetherian
>
> Proof:
>
> - $1 \iff 2$. Generators of the $\mathfrak m$ ideal are elements $\pi \in K$ of minimal positive valuation
> - $2 \implies 3$. Follows from $2 \implies 1$ because in every ideal there is an element with minimal valuation.
> - $3 \implies 4$. If every ideal is principal, then it's in particular finitely generated, and so the ring is noetherian
> - $4 \implies 2$. Let $\mathfrak m = \langle x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\rangle$ be an ideal and wlog assume that $v(x_1) \le \ldots \le v(x_n)$. Then $v(x_i/x_1) \ge 0$ and so $x_i/x_1 \in \mathcal O$, so $\mathfrak m = \langle x_1 \rangle$.

What was its title/author?

Comment: These seem to be pretty standard knowledge, so it could literally be any article or lecture notes which somehow and for some reason contain an introduction to valuation theory. I guess there are at least dozens of those out there on the web, https://www.google.com/search?q=introduction+to+valued+fields. As for commonly referenced books, I would quickly look at Engler/ Prestel, and Gouvea, and Serre's *Local Fields* (although Serre in particular usually is so short he might just state that implicitly in the middle of some proof).

Comment: Yes, I am a bit familiar with valuation theory and I am also aware that this is common knowledge - for example Cassels - Local fields ($1 \iff 2$ only, on page 42), or Gouvea's textbook ($2 \iff 1 \implies 3$ on page 51). The proof that I posted wasn't invented by me but discovered in some other source that I am really curious to find. The question is more on the book (or paper, can't remember what it was) than on the proof itself.